# An alternative to native HTML5 datepicker

Tags: open-source, cross-platform, jquery, html

HTML5 native date picker supports the following features

- keyboard operability (even assisted keyboard entry since it jumps
  from month to date to year without having user enter the separator),
- localization (different languages are supported as per system
  language),
- auto-correction of dates (if user enter month as 13, it
  auto corrects it to 12)
- date-picker display is also keyboard operable
  (I can navigate from one month to another and one date to another via
  keyboard)
- browser support is good (almost all latest versions of most
  known browsers supports it)
- Appears on mobile devices in [this way](https://hprog99.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/uvqx2l-png.jpeg) (optional)

But this native date picker format [cannot be changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format/9519493#9519493) programmatically. So, is there a open-source date picker available which supports these features?

Comment: @izzy this is the new question, older one is deleted. Thanks for your interest. Hope I find a solution here.